# Can we do file handling from executable created by py2exe in Python?

Tags: python, py2exe

I wrote below code

```
f = open("tt.txt","w")
print >> f, 123
val = input("Enter the number_")
print val*val
raw_input()
f.close()
```

And then created executable through py2exe. On clicking on executable a window pops which asks for a number give square of it, but doesn't create a file like program does on simple execution. Why it is happening? Is there anyway to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file will be created in the current working directory. To get the working directory, do:

```
 import os
 print os.getcwd()
```

The file should be created in that directory. Make sure you have write access to it.